# QGIS: GPS Tracking with improved Altitude

Tags: qgis, gps, rtklib

I am preparing for archeological fieldwork in Sudan. I recently came up with RTK equipment and software using RTKlib to export the real time corrected data (cm level) to QGIS via a simulated NMEA device.

However I checked the NMEA data flow and it includes elevations down to mm; in QGIS only one decimal is given. Is there any way to improve this and have the altitude information shown in cm as well?

Also QGIS applies geoid corrections but I wish to use ellipsoidal elevation. And finally right now I have to include the elevation data manually in the datamask for every point while saving. Is there a way QGIS can save the elevation in points and polylines?

Comment: These all sounds like feature requests (and good ones). Please write up [some issue tickets at hub.qgis.org](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues). The elevation precision increase might be as easy as updating the GUI. In master branch, there has been work on improved distance measurements, which might help with the geoid vs. ellipsoid issue.

Comment: thank you
ok i will do so in a few day if no one has a other solution. but does someone know how to add z values zo shape files other than a atribute but geometry so i can export its shape as 3d as well.
Thanks
 Frank